# I want add pdf page to UIPageViewController view

Tags: iphone, pdf, uipageviewcontroller

I am new in iPhone application development, I am developing one iPad application development. In this application i am using UIPageViewController. Now i want pdf file page to display UIPageViewControlller view. how to read pdf page and how to add UIPageViewController please give some me example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a PDF page to a CALayer or to a UIImage. Apple even have sample code to show how draw a large PDF in a , [Zoomable UIScrollview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) and for page view controller i havent try out this but may be this [link](http://chillysky.com/UIPageViewControllerDemo.zip.) will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a sample code project called `ZoomingPDFReader`. It's a simple app that displays a page of a PDF. Put this into your app. Keep track of the page number, and then display the corresponding PDF page.

You can download the source code [Here](https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF)